# Is there a way to temporarily parent a vertex group to a bone?

Tags: rigging

How can you temporarily parent certain vertex groups to bones? Something like the "Child of" constraint but with vertex groups instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the hook modifier is what you're after.

Without any parent relationship :

1. Select your mesh
2. add a hook modifier
3. in Object, select your armature
4. in Bone, select the "parent" bone
5. in Vertex Group, select the "child" vertex group
6. You can now move the bone and animate the strengh of the modifier:

[image]

[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z7WXOM3iQYM)'s also a good tutorial about it.

Comment: Please leave more than only a link as an answer and at least include relevant information from the link. If the link goes down, then your answer loses much of it's value.

Comment: hope it's better now.

Answer (score 0):

You can parent using the following steps:

1. Select the mesh then select the armature
2. ctrl+P then parent with empty groups

After that once you want to clear the parenting:

1. go to the vertex group menu in the properties panel
2. Click the small down arrow
3. Clear all vertex groups

Comment: I don't think you understood what I meant, deleting the vertex groups gets rid of parenting all together. As an example, the idea is to temporarily parent the vertex groups in one part of an animation, and unparent it and/or parent it to another mesh in the other part, so it would work like the "Child of" constraint.

Comment: @Wiirexu answer edited. Instead of deleting the vertex group you clear it, it will be in the same list.

Comment: Problem is you can't animate that, however I already found that the hook modifier can achieve what I want to do. Thanks for the reply anyway!